# Why does RuboCop suggest replacing .times.map with Array.new?

Tags: ruby, performance, rubocop

RuboCop suggests:

> Use `Array.new` with a block instead of `.times.map.`

In the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Performance/TimesMap) for the cop:

> This cop checks for .times.map calls. In most cases such calls can be replaced with an explicit array creation.

Examples:

```
# bad
9.times.map do |i|
  i.to_s
end

# good
Array.new(9) do |i|
  i.to_s
end
```

I know it can be replaced, but I feel `9.times.map` is closer to English grammar, and it's easier to understand what the code does.

Why should it be replaced?

Comment: Note that it's in the "Performance" group (as you can see from your link), which is a bit of a hint. :-)

Comment: All performance cops were adapted from: https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby :-)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The latter is more performant; here is an explanation: [Pull request where this cop was added](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/pull/2583)

> It checks for calls like this:
>
> ```
> 9.times.map { |i| f(i) }
> 9.times.collect(&foo)
> ```
>
> and suggests using this instead:
>
> ```
> Array.new(9) { |i| f(i) }
> Array.new(9, &foo)
> ```
>
> The new code has approximately the same size, but uses fewer method
>   calls, consumes less memory, works a tiny bit faster and in my opinion
>   is more readable.
>
> I've seen many occurrences of times.{map,collect} in different
>   well-known projects: Rails, GitLab, Rubocop and several closed-source
>   apps.
>
> Benchmarks:
>
> ```
> Benchmark.ips do |x|
>   x.report('times.map') { 5.times.map{} }
>   x.report('Array.new') { Array.new(5){} }
>   x.compare!
> end
> __END__
> Calculating -------------------------------------
>            times.map    21.188k i/100ms
>            Array.new    30.449k i/100ms
> -------------------------------------------------
>            times.map    311.613k (± 3.5%) i/s -      1.568M
>            Array.new    590.374k (± 1.2%) i/s -      2.954M
>
> Comparison:
>            Array.new:   590373.6 i/s
>            times.map:   311612.8 i/s - 1.89x slower
> ```
>
> I'm not sure now that Lint is the correct namespace for the cop. Let
>   me know if I should move it to Performance.
>
> Also I didn't implement autocorrection because it can potentially
>   break existing code, e.g. if someone has Fixnum#times method redefined
>   to do something fancy. Applying autocorrection would break their code.

Comment: Yeah, that actually seems like a good idea. It pre-allocates an array of the correct size. `times` gives no such heads up to `map` so it has to guess and potentially resize.

Comment: Please don't just post a link, summarize the linked content in a paragraph.

Comment: And the link doesn't even explain why it is slower.

Comment: The question was "Why it should be replaced", not "why it is slower".  Following the best practices does not mean full understanding of underling reasons. @akuhn

Comment: In 2 years, rubocop might have been moved to another repo, and the link might be dead. We're all here to educate ourselves : there's a difference between not understanding everything, and not even trying to understand anything.

Comment: "Following the best practices does not mean full understanding of underling reasons" <--- this is totally untrue

Answer (score 16):

**If you feel it is more readable, go with it.**

This is a performance rule and most codepaths in your application are probably not performance critical. Personally, I am always open to favor readability over premature optimization.

That said

```
100.times.map { ... }
```

- `times` creates an `Enumerator` object
- `map` enumerates over that object without being able to optimize, for example the size of the array is not known upfront and it might have to reallocate more space dynamically and it has to enumerate over the values by calling `Enumerable#each` since `map` is implemented that way

Whereas

```
Array.new(100) { ... }
```

- `new` allocates an array of size `N`
- And then uses a native loop to fill in the values

Comment: _**"If you feel it is more readable go with it."**_ Thank you! Plus, if you look at @Drenmi's answer, he shows that the `times` is only 60% slower than `Array`. If it was 1000% slower, then it might sway your decision. But these kinds of minor performance differences would be outweighed by long-term Human readability.

Answer (score 6):

When you need to map the result of a block invoked a fixed amount of times, you have an option between:

```
Array.new(n) { ... }
```

and:

```
n.times.map { ... }
```

The latter one is about 60% slower for `n = 10`, which goes down to around 40% for `n > 1_000`.

*Note: logarithmic scale!*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding what the performance difference is and for including a fancy log graph!!